# How to set byte-recompile-directory use a cache directory?

Tags: emacs, compilation

I use the (byte-recompile-directory (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d") 0) to generate .elc file ,it improve the emacs startup,but i wan to set byte-recompile-directory to use a cache folder not generate .elc files in same folder.and i want to know that do i need to declare emacs to use cache folder instead of el file？ Will emacs automatically load these ·.elc· files? like this

```
├── core
│   ├── core-keybinds.el
│   ├── core-provider.el
│   └── core.el
├── early-init.el
├── init.el
```

but when i use (byte-recompile-directory (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d") 0)

```
├── core
│   ├── core-keybinds.el
│   ├── core-keybinds.elc
│   ├── core-provider.el
│   ├── core-provider.elc
│   └── core.el
│   ├── core.elc
├── early-init.el
|── early-init.elc
├── init.el
├── init.elc
```

maybe the best way like this

```
├── .cache
│   ├── core-keybinds.elc
│   ├── core-provider.elc
│   ├── core.elc
│   └── init.elc
│   └── early-init.elc
├── core
│   ├── core-keybinds.el
│   ├── core-provider.el
│   └── core.el
├── early-init.el
├── init.el
```

then how to let emacs to load these .elc files...i am new come to emacs.so need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `byte-compile-dest-file-function` to a function that puts the files in the cache directory:

```
(defun my-bytecomp-dest-file (source)
  (expand-file-name (file-name-nondirectory source) "~/.cache/"))

(setq byte-compile-dest-file-function 'my-bytecomp-dest-file)
```

You'll need to add the cache directory to the load path explicitly for the `.elc` files to be found:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.cache/")
```

Then you can load the files using e.g. `(require 'core)` or `(load "core")`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the correct way to write loadpath and elc files? How do I specify the loading of elc?